# Reading Image from SQL Error in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception

I have a SQLite DB I have field called PersonalPic of Type BLOB

this is code in which I save image to SQLite

```
cm.CommandText = "insert into People(Name,FullName,FatherName,MotherName,NationalID,Mobile,Phone,Birth,Intma,Info,Address,CuAddress,PersonalPic,Pics) values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox6.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"','"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"','"+textBox8.Text+"','"+textBox9.Text+"','"+textBox10.Text+"','"+textBox11.Text+"','"+ConvertToString(personalpic)+"','"+ConvertToString(pic)+"')";
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();



public string ConvertToString(String path)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] rawData = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(rawData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            fs.Close();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(rawData);

            return base64String;
        }
```

It`s saved without no problems when I try to retrieve image it gives me Parameter is no valid Exception

```
SQLiteDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                        textBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                        textBox2.Text = reader["FullName"].ToString();
                        textBox3.Text = reader["FatherName"].ToString();
                        textBox4.Text = reader["MotherName"].ToString();
                        textBox5.Text = reader["NationalID"].ToString();
                        textBox6.Text = reader["Mobile"].ToString();
                        textBox7.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
                        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(reader["Birth"].ToString());
                        textBox8.Text = reader["Intma"].ToString();
                        textBox9.Text = reader["Info"].ToString();
                        byte[] photoarray = (byte[])reader["PersonalPic"];
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photoarray);
                        MessageBox.Show(photoarray.Length.ToString());
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);



                }
            }
            reader.Close();
```

Exception is in the Line (pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms))

Please Help!!

Comment: Your INSERT query is completely vulnerable to SQL injection at the moment. Use a parameterized query instead.

Comment: Also, please show us the SELECT statement you're using, I think you might be forgetting to select PersonalPic.

Comment: cm.CommandText = "select * from People where NationalID='" + nationalid + "'";

and no danger from SQL Injection cause It`s Small Local Company Application

Comment: +1 on parameterized query. Its actually going to be easier to do. You can just pass the `byte[]` into the parameterized query. However...my suggestion is to use an ORM. I suggest using nuget to get `Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact`.

Comment: I think Eoin Campbell has the right diagnosis for your problem below. As to parameterized queries, it doesn't matter how few people use your program; you need to do them. They protect you from purposful and accidental SQL injections.

Comment: I used parameterized queries but also with the same exception if someone can provide me with simple code I would be grateful

Comment: 1) Getting the same error when using parameterized queries is no reason for not using them, but for fixing the code. 2) Remove the conversion to base64 string or convert it back properly. You can't instantiate a bitmap from a base64 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the horrendous sql inject insert statement, you're converting your picture `byte` array to a B64 `string`. And you're not converting it back on the other side. You're passing complete garbage data to your pictureBox. Either convert it back from `byte[]` -> B64 `string` and then decode it back to a `byte[]`.. or just don't save it as a B64 `string` in the first place

Replace `ConvertToString` with `ConvertToBlob`

```
    public byte[] ConvertToBlob(String path)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,
        FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] rawData = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(rawData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();


        return rawData;
    }
```

And pass the raw data Byte[] directly to your SQL Query (which you need to rewrite as a parameterised query).

Comment: Please give me some example

Comment: byte[] photoarray = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])reader["PersonalPic"]));
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photoarray);
                        MessageBox.Show(photoarray.Length.ToString());
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

still give me the same exception